# Why was this question migrated?

Tags: discussion, migration

I don't think [my question](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/52473/what-is-a-typical-elongation-of-a-dynamic-climbing-rope) should have been migrated. I'm asking a sports equipment question, not a physics theory question. I would compare my question to "what is a typical PSI of a football used in the NFL?" Surely sports and physics are related, but my question was not physics related, but rather just asking about specifications of a piece of sport equipment.

Comment: FYI, you just got an answer on [Physics SE](http://physics.stackexchange.com/a/52475)

Comment: Now, it's on [The Great Outdoors](http://outdoors.stackexchange.com/questions/3605/what-is-a-typical-elongation-of-a-dynamic-climbing-rope)

Answer (score 1):

The reason: expertise.

As I state, I understand your question was in reference to equipment used in the sport of climbing. However, you seem to ask what elongation specifies a dynamic climbing rope and a static climbing rope. The expertise on Physics SE, compared to Sports SE, I felt would better help you clarify that discrepancy.

For example, if you asked which climbing rope, static or dynamic, is better suited for [condition: sharp rocks, smooth rocks, wet rocks, etc.]...it would line up more with the expertise on Sports SE. There is some overlap...perhaps this question may also be in the line of expertise offered by [The Great Outdoors](https://outdoors.stackexchange.com/).

In addition, "What is a typical PSI of a football used in the NFL?" is [8.6-15.7 psi](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Football_(ball)#Dimensions). It comes down to expertise. For example, I would not go to a sports statistician and ask him about the optimal tire pressure for the racetrack I race on.

Comment: The Great Outdoors has a [`rope`](http://outdoors.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/rope) tag. Based on how you ask your question, you have the following: Physics SE for elongation, Sports SE for "sports equipment," and The Great Outdoors SE for usage of rope.

Comment: @Sancho It's not necessarily that we don't have the expertise...it's that other SE sites may have the expertise already in place to best help the user. However, I do agree with giving it a few days before migration...also to determine if a bounty is set on the question or not.